# Is there any API to get sheets modified or created in last 7 days in smart sheet

Tags: smartsheet-api

I need to use smart sheet API to get list of sheets which were created of modified in last 7 days and user has access. I have gone through the documents but only API I can find returns all sheets for which user has access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [List Sheets](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#list-sheets) operation accepts a `modifiedSince` parameter that you can specify if you only want sheets that have been created or modified after a certain date/time.

For example, the following request returns all sheets that the user (who owns the API access token used to make the call) has access to that have been created or modified on or after July 1, 2019.

```
GET https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets?modifiedSince=2019-07-01T00:00:00Z
```

Note that in the previous example, the time portion of the `modifiedSince` query string parameter value is set to 00:00:00 (start of the day). If you only want sheets created or modified after a certain *time* on the specified date, set that value accordingly.